# how does the switch case work exactly, I want to be able to understand it completely

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to completely understand this block of code, I think I understand most of it but some parts I'm not so sure. Would appreciated being able to clear some stuff up.

```
    private void equals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] hold = Sum.Text.Split(' ');//splits text with a space, not 100% sure this is correct
        switch (hold[1]) //not sure
        {
            case "+":// + is name of the case
                Result.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(hold[0]) + Convert.ToDouble(hold[2])).ToString(); 
                //displays in the result textbox > converts hold[0](first number) to double, 
                //hold[1] is the operation sign(+) > + sign to add the next number > convert hold[2] to double > converts it all to a string.

                break;//terminates the loop once the case has been selected.
```

Comment: have you read any documentation on how the switch case works if not start reading some tutorials / documentation http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/switch-statement/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is what you don't understand? basically what it is doing is getting the value in position 1 of the array and comparing with the different cases you may have. So, in this case, if arr[1] equals '+' then it steps into the case, else it breaks. You can have more than one "case val:... break; "
Usually something like this:

```
switch(value)
{
  case "val1":
      code
      break;
  case "val2":
      code
      break;
  ...
  default:
      code
      return;
}
```

Comment: Also important to remember that without the break (or a return) you will fall through the next case. So in your sample removing the first break means that the code for val2 executes even when value = val1. (I'm sure you were aware just pointing it out for OP)

Comment: Thank you, you have answered my question!:)